# Put results from Find-function (including extra columns for each result) into array vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox, userform

This question is based on a tip I got in the forum some other day, but since this completely changed the problem I'm creating a new post (it seemed a much better solution than the one I proposed but I'm having some issues).

The rationale of my code is to **search** up and **find** entries based on ID in column A (from criteria input in txtbox); **if** the row matches the search criteria **then** I want the data from column A to J for that entry to be stored in a **dynamic array**. All the matching entries will be stored there. This array will be used to display all the relevant entries in a **listbox** in a userform.

The code is the following:

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Variant
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim row_number As Integer
Dim item_in_review As Variant
Dim y As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant

y = lstSearch.ListCount


Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("a")
lastrow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strSearch = txtSearch.Text
    Set aCell = sht.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
         GoTo wfrefvalid
     Else
MsgBox "Oops! That Work File does not exist. Please try again.", Title:="Try again"
txtSearch.Value = ""
        End If
    Exit Sub

wfrefvalid:
row_number = 0
'clears the listbox so that you have dont have a continuously growing list
lstSearch.Clear
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
ReDim Preserve Arr(item_in_review + 1)
item_in_review = sht.Range("A" & row_number)
If item_in_review = txtSearch.Text Then
Arr = item_in_review.Range("A" & row_number & ":J" & row_number)
End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""

lstSearch.List = Arr

End Sub
```

The code isn't giving any debugging-errors, however it's also not doing *anything* when I press the search button. I think the area where I'm struggling is defining the array, and **adding** each entry to it as the find-function loops through the table (ie the last 12 or so pieces of code).

ANyone have any tips for adding the data from the search (including the extra columns) to the array?

Comment: Excel has a great set of [debugging tools](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) that should help you find the issue.  I'd recommend using F8 to execute your code one line at a time.  Hovering over variables will allow you to preview their contents.  From the view menu, the Immediate Window and Locals Window will help you inspect what your code is doing and the general state of Excel.

Comment: Where is your code? It needs to be in the `Worksheet` module for the worksheet where the button named "cmdFind" is located - Does the event currently get triggered? (since you say it's not doing **anything**)

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Item_In_Review` is a variant, but in fact you are assigning a string to it: `Item_In_Review = Sht.Range("A" & Row_Number)`. It would be better to add `.Value` to that line so that you don't become confused as to what you are assigning. Then you correctly compare that string with another string. I suspect that they actually never match because if they would the next line should throw an error. `Item_In_Review` is a string, not a worksheet. If it is a Ws name your code should be like `Sheets(Item_In_Review)`. Again, add `.Value` at the end of that line.

Comment: Hello @RikSportel . The code is in the userform where the button and the other controls are located. The code is running because when I search up ID's that I know doesn't exist the debugger starts with the messagebox (as seen in the code) that ID wasn't found. Thus it may be that the code technically isn't wrong, but it simply produces nothing. It's difficult to debug because there's a lot of other code in the userform as well (some of which doesn't work).

Comment: `Arr = Sheets(Item_In_Review).Range("A" & Row_Number & ":J" & Row_Number).Value` would assign the value of the range to Arr. If you want that range assigned to Arr(0) you would have to say so. For that purpose you also need a counter for the index of Arr which is missing in your code.

Comment: @Variatus that's really a good point. I hadn't thought through that syntax well enough. item_in_review in this case is supposed to be the item that is currently being compared to the txtSearch.Value

Comment: @Variatus so I want to loop through the table and add each matching item. So I need a dedicated counter for this? Can you advise on the syntax for this?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint next to any line in your code, see the current values of the variables by hovering over them and step through your code one line at a time with F8. Observe that your code will create an Arr if both Item_in_Review and txtSearch.Text are ""

Comment: Declare the counter as long, say `Dim i As Long`. Then follow up with `i = i + 1` each time you created an Arr element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code would to be like this.

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Variant
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim row_number As Integer
Dim item_in_review As Variant
Dim y As Integer
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim rngDB As Range
Dim strAddress As String, n As Long

y = lstSearch.ListCount


Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("a")
lastrow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngDB = sht.Range("a1", "a" & lastrrow)
strSearch = txtSearch.Text
    With rngDB
        Set aCell = .Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
          If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            strAddress = aCell.Address
            Do
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To 10, 1 To n)
                For i = 1 To 10
                    Arr(i, n) = aCell(1, i)
                Next i
                Set aCell = .FindNext(aCell)
            Loop While strAddress <> aCell.Address

         Else
            MsgBox "Oops! That Work File does not exist. Please try again.", Title:="Try again"
            txtSearch.Value = ""
        End If
    End With
    If n = 1 Then
        lstSearch.List = Arr
    ElseIf n > 1 Then
        lstSearch.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr)
    End If
End Sub
```